# How do date comparisons work in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am new to Rail and trying to make a query in ActiveRecord.  I am trying to get all of the records with the status of 'Landed', that are over 60 days old.  My query works up to the point of getting all of the projects with the status of 'Landed'.  When I add in the last condition of "created_at < ? ", then I always get an empty relation.  I know that I have projects that fit that description, so I am doing something wrong in my query and dont understand.  I believe my error is in the date comparison, but I am not sure.

```
1. Projects
    belongs_to :status
    has_many :project_status_histories
2. Status
    has_many :projects
    has_many :project_status_histories
3. Project_Status_Histories
    belongs_to :status
    belongs_to :project

Project.find(:all, :joins => [:project_status_histories, :status], :conditions => {:projects => {:status_id => Status.where(:name => 'Landed').first.id }, :project_status_histories => {:created_at => ["created_at < ?", (Date.today - 60.days)]}})
```

I have tried to build the query, step by step, with the dbconsole and am not having any luck.  Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's the date arithmetic. One nice way to do this would be with named scopes. Add the following to project.rb:

```
scope :landed, joins(:status).where('statuses.name' => 'Landed')
scope :recent, lambda \
              { joins(:project_status_histories) \
              .where('project_status_histories.created_at < ?', Date.today - 60.days) }
```

Then you can retrieve the relevant records/objects with:

```
Project.landed.recent
```

This worked for me in my test. You should also check out the rails guide, from which I stole most of this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Yep scoped views are cleaner, this solution is way better than mine. ;)

Comment: I added the scope and I can now use them separately, but they will not chain.    `scope :landed, find(:all, :joins => :status, :conditions => {:projects => {:status_id => Status.where(:name => 'Landed')}}` and `scope :recent, lambda{joins(:project_status_histories).where('project_status_histories.created_at < ?', Date.today - 60.day)}`  I must be returning a relation that I am not expecting.

Comment: When I chain the scope as in `Project.landed.recent`, I get a "undefined method recent" error.

Comment: I deleted my little test project so it will be awhile before I can test it, but I'm guessing that your `landed` scope is returning an array of project objects (because you are using `find` there), and the `recent` scope is returning an Arel relation, so when you call `recent` you are calling it on an array of project objects, not a relation. In my example both scopes are returning relations. You could test it by replacing your `landed` scope code with the code from my example and seeing what happens.

Comment: Also I just noticed that the `recent` scope is really finding old stuff, not recent stuff, so it's horribly named. Sorry I didn't read more carefully.

Comment: Recent returns a relation and landed returns an array, so I can call `Project.recent.landed`.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a little bit complicated...

I would rather do it like this:

```
Project.where("status.name = ? AND project_status_histories.created_at < ?", "Landed", Time.now.day - 60.days)
```

I think this should work better. Let me know if it doesn't, maybe I've wrote something wrong, unfortunately I can't test it right now...

[Edit]

You also might want to see what is the generated SQL, use the "explain" method for that, just add it to the end of your query and print the result, for instance with your query:

```
Project.find(:all, :joins => [:project_status_histories, :status], :conditions => {:projects => {:status_id => Status.where(:name => 'Landed').first.id }, :project_status_histories => {:created_at => ["created_at < ?", (Date.today - 60.days)]}}).explain
```

Comment: Prefer the solution of Steve Rowley ;)